# Errors in baking normals. I'm either doing something super dumb or I'm not using normals the way they're supposed to be used. Please help

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

Just can't seem to bake normals the right way. I've tried multiple tutorials and read quite a few blog posts. I'm trying to make a whole mech. Best outcome would be to bake the complete mech in a 1-2k texture. However, that is turning out to be a nightmare so I'm thinking of doing 512x512 or 1k textures for different parts of the mech. Now the problem is even the smallest parts are getting errors which I can't seem to solve. Am I doing something wrong? Is Blender not suited for this job? Or are normal maps not viable here and I MUST use geometry? I've been stuck on it for a week now and I'd really appreciate it if you guys could help me fix this ASAP. Here's the image with (hopefully) all the relevant information: [image: Middle one is the high and low poly, left is low poly, right is high poly.]

[File](http://%5B%3Cimg%20src=%22https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2WVOV9ow%22%20/%3E%5D(https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2WVOV9ow/))

PS:I'm trying to make a mobile game and that is why I want to keep the textures small.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2WVOV9ow" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2WVOV9ow/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The baking works fine, the problem is that all your details are completely parallel or perpendicular to the low poly faces normals. Baking the normals will only be able to scan the faces normals that are not parallel or perpendicular to the rays, bake normals save the faces normals direction, not the faces height.

Here, no bake possible:

[image]

Here, the oblique faces are not perpendicular or parallel to the ray so they will be baked:

[image]

If your high-poly ever go through the surface of your low-poly, tweak the *Ray Distance* value so that it nows begin a bit before the low-poly surface (you may also need to tweak the *Extrusion* value):

[image]

In your case, if I scale down one of your details and bake, as the normals are now oblique it will be saved on the normal map, the other ones won't:

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you help me with selected to active setttings? I sort of understand what they are for but I think they kinda do the same thing, right?

Comment: your settings are good, they are used to choose where the ray must begin (in scene units) if the high poly ever go through the low-poly surface, it won't fix anything to change their current settings, again the problem here is that your details are either parallel or perpendicular to the baking ray, so your rays can't record anything

Comment: Okay I fixed it as you said and I'm getting much better results. Thanks!